# Deep Learning on how to find out the body measurement (e.g. shoulder length, waist, hips, legs length etc) from mobile camera captured images?

Tags: deep-learning, image-recognition

I do understand that there are plenty of mobile apps available for body measurement (e.g. MTailor) or creating 3D model (3dlook).

What I would like to find out is how we can use deep learning to achieve the accurate body measurement/3D model with just smart phone camera?

For example, MTailor can predict one's body measurement quite accurately given the cameara angle/camera distance from the human and human height. Can we do the same using deep learning with some labeled images to achieve the same accurate body measurement prediction?

Thanks

Regards,
Han

Comment: Why do you feel that deep learning is a good way to solve this problem?

Comment: I suggest you replace the word 'predict' with 'estimate'.  This is a geometry estimation problem.  It is not a prediction problem.  Prediction implies time is involved.

Comment: Hi Brian, apologize for the late reply. We used the mobile app front end to mark some of the body measurement data points and control the camera angle/distance from person. Finally all the data coming in with pretty accurate measurement of the body.